# Python dynamically import classes an call their functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one Abstract Animal class.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Animal(ABC):  # Inherit from ABC(Abstract base class)
    @abstractmethod  # Decorator to define an abstract method
    def feed(self):
        pass
```

And three classes which Implements it

```
from Animal import Animal

class Lion(Animal):
   def feed(self):
        print("Feeding a lion with raw meat!")
```

```
from Animal import Animal

class Panda(Animal):
    def feed(self):
        print("Feeding a panda with some tasty bamboo!")
```

```
from Animal import Animal


class Snake(Animal):
    def feed(self):
        print("Feeding a snake with mice!")
```

Now I just want to import all classes, which are in the project folder and call the feed function of all classes, when there is a feed function.

```
from glob import glob
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
   for file in glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "*.py")):
       name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
       # add package prefix to name, if required
       module = __import__(name)
       try:
            module.feed()
       except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

My Problem is now, that I get the errors:

> module 'Animal' has no attribute 'feed'

> module 'Lion' has no attribute 'feed'

> module 'main' has no attribute 'feed'

> module 'Panda' has no attribute 'feed'

> module 'Snake' has no attribute 'feed'

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You say you wish to call `feed` on the **classes** … these are modules … hence why it’s not there …

Comment: Okay and I get the class then instead of the module?

Comment: I think you are importing the 'Module' but not creating the objects.  After module = __import__(name), add {obj = module.name} and then change module.feed() to obj.feed()

Comment: `getattr(module, name)().feed()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it your files are called `Snake.py`, `Panda.py` etc. If so then you are invoking `feed()` on the files not the classes. You need to get the modules (which you've done), then get the class and then call the method:

```
from glob import glob
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
   for file in glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "*.py")):
       name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
       if name == "Animal" or name == "main":  # avoid main.py and Animal.py
           continue
       # add package prefix to name, if required
       module = __import__(name)
       try:
           # get the class
           cls = getattr(module, name)
           # instantiate the class and call the method
           cls().feed()
       except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Ive also included a safety check to exclude main.py and Animal.py